# Convert 64-bit ISO to 32-bit

Tags: iso, conversion, 64bit, 32bit

I have a Linux bootable ISO of Blancco Drive Eraser which only supports 64-bit CPUs.
How can I use this ISO with a 32-bit CPU?

I want to erase the onboard eMMC on tablets. So far I've failed to find a 32-bit ISO of Blancco.

Comment: which x86 CPU nowadays doesn't support 64-bit ISA?

Comment: This is probably an XY problem. I don't know what your tablet is but probably it's in the same category as this question: [How can I install 64-bit Ubuntu 15.10 on my UEFI-IA32 Bay Trail tablet?](https://askubuntu.com/q/727664/253474)

Answer (score 3):

You can’t convert a 64-bit operating system to run on a 32-bit CPU.

Regarding your specific scenario, if you have a Blancco license, you should ask them directly (and you should be able to download the relevant image from your account). Blancco Drive Eraser isn’t intended for individual use anyway (see [this page](https://www.blancco.com/demo/free-strategy-session-blancco-drive-eraser/) for details), and Blancco suggest you use [DBAN](https://dban.org/) instead. The current version of DBAN is [available for 32-bit x86 systems](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dban/files/dban/dban-2.3.0/dban-2.3.0_i586.iso/download).

Comment: I did try DBAN, it does not boot in UEFI system. I have couple of tablet PCS which has only 32bit UEFI system with windows 8 install.
we do data wipeing and can not load Blancco.
we also used whitecanyon in past but same problem. Both wipes Apple Systems, other UEFI base PCs but couple of tablet like PCs are not loading software.